# Embedded device for deploying network probes

Tags: linux, network-monitoring, embedded, embedded-linux

Our environment has a multitude of remote subnets that we monitor by deploying Linux-based probes running various network monitoring software and other handy tools. Currently we're using surplus-ed Dell OptiPlex GXs whose chief advantages are 1) their smallish form factor and 2) they're free. However they have a number of disadvantages: They're noisy, bulky, and prone to hardware failure (mostly due to age... they're at least five years old before they get to us).

We're looking to move to something smaller, quieter and purpose-built for this kind of work. The [Soekris 4501](http://soekris.com/products/net4501-1.html) (which I have had great results with in other places) and [ALIX 2D3](http://pcengines.ch/alix2d3.htm) immediately come to mind. However, they're both lacking the killer feature which is the *absence* of external AC adapter.

The ideal platform would have:

- No external AC adapter
- Power over Ethernet capabilities
- 3 or more NICs (10/100 is sufficient)
- Serial port console access
- Few or (preferably) no fans
- Compact FLASH for storage
- The ability to happily run Linux or BSD
- Between $150 and $200 per unit

The Soekris and ALIX products have all of these features except they require an AC adapter (albeit a small one).

- Has anyone come across a platform that manages to meet all these criteria?
- What's your preference for an "embedded" platform that serves as a network probe/swiss army knife?

Comment: What's the problem with the external power brick?  If it's just that you don't want another loose piece, why not just epoxy the brick to the case of the Soekris - it'd still be plenty small.  For the Alix, it's not clear what sort of enclosure they come with, if you can choose your own, could you get a big enough enclosure to hold the power brick?

Comment: Also, you could get POE splitter so that you do not need to deploy power-bricks at the remote site but use the POE splitter to connect the device power to the POE power instead.

Comment: @Ward: Yeah, it'd be nice to have something cleaner. I think I could also use a larger case with either the Soekirs or the ALIX boards. For that matter a "bookshelf"-size computer might work as well.
@sybreon: PoE is definitely the other way to go, especially in places where we don't have room for a power adapter or mounting one would be ugly.

Comment: I've used these before, but they were a little more expensive than 200$/unit (but had a ton of other monitoring features): http://www.netbotz.com/products/appliances.html

Answer (score 2):

The Soekris 4511 will do PoE:

> "Supports Power over Ethernet according to the 802.3af standard"
>
> http://soekris.com/net4511.html